# Problem with vanilla Texlive installation on Debian (Probably with dummy equivs)

Tags: installing, debian, texlive-2018

I have some problem with my installation of Texlive Vanilla 2018 on my Debian Stretch.

Everything going well during installation but when I am trying to use Texmaker or LyX, they don't work and don't find any package.

At the end of the vanilla installation, I have tested that everything working well with :

> tex --version
>
> latex sample2e.tex
>
> xdvi sample2e.dvi
>
> pdflatex sample2e.tex

following this page :
https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-fr/texlive-fr.html#x1-350003.4

And I obtain the right pdf and everything was fine with this method.

So, I think that there is a problem with the equivs dummy package or with the PATH.

In LyX, all the document class are unavailable and in TeXmaker, the command:  "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex" is not working.

I already succeed to install Texlive Vanilla on my previous computer on Debian Stretch (With texlive2016 1 years ago) but it was difficult too. This time I don't see any solution. The Vanilla Texlive is my nightmares with Debian using.

Is there a particularity with the 2018 teXlive Vanilla ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  So you could compile the sample file but not your own code? If yes it could help to see your code, as minimal working example.

Comment: How exactly did you add the tl18 path? Who exactly are you starting texmaker or LyX? Command line or via a menu?

Comment: I can compile if I use the sample in the terminal. But I can't compile anything with teXmaker or LyX


I have used : 
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH


I start Texmaker and Lyx via the toolbar (not sure of the english word), i am using XFCE on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of PATH setup. According to your comment you are using

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

which is fine for a terminal session, but **not** for the GUI you are using. If you are on Debian, you will need to do something else, there are two ways:

- (for all users) either you set the PATH globally in `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh` where you put the three export lines you mentioned
- (only for you) add the three export lines to `$HOME/.xsessionrc` which is sourced

After one of these changes and re-logging in the GUI environment should have a `PATH` setting including the local TL, and the TeX GUIs should pick it up automatically.